# Constructing diagonalizable matricies such that matrix exponential of their product is easy to compute.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-exponential, hamilton-equations

**Question** Consider a *real skew-symmetric* matrix $J$ and a *real symmetric positive semi-definite* matrix $A$. We want to parameterize a construction of these matrices so that it is easy to compute $e^{JA}$. How can we do this?

**Attempt**

1. A real skew-symmetric matrix admits an Eigendecomposition as $J = U^{-1}_J D_J U_J$, where $U_J$ is a unitary matrix and $D_J$ is a diagonal matrix with purely complex values.
2. A real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix admits an Eigendecomposition as $A = U^{-1}_A D_A U_A$, where $U_A$ is an orthogonal matrix and $D_A$ is a diagonal matrix with purely real non-negative values.
3. The matrix exponential of $J$ is $e^J = U^{-1}_J e^{D_J} U_J$, where $e^{D_J}$ is just the exponentiation of the diagonals.
4. The matrix exponential of $A$ is $e^A = U^{-1}_A e^{D_A} U_A$, where $e^{D_A}$ is just the exponentiation of the diagonals.
5. We have that $e^{JA} = e^{U^{-1}_J D_J U_J U^{-1}_A D_A U_A}$. How can we simplify this?
6. What is an easy way to construct $U_J$ and $U_A$?

**Remark**
The solution to a Hamiltonian dynamical system with a *quadratic* Hamiltonian is given by $x(t) = e^{JA(t - t_0)}x(t_0)$. How can we construct $J$ and $A$ so that this is easy to simplify?

Comment: @user10354138 If $\ JA=AJ\ $ then $\ JA\ $ would be skew-symmetric, therefore unitarily diagonalizable,$$(JA)^T=(AJ)^T=J^TA^T=-JA\ ,$$ and   hence would appear to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that $J$ and $A$ commute in the context of Hamiltonian dynamics? How can I construct them by their *simultaneous diagonalization*?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the answer to your first question.  That seemed to be suggested by user1035138's comment, but that's now been deleted, so perhaps he or she has had second thoughts.

Comment: If $\ A\ $ and $\ J\ $ *do* commute, however, you can easily find a complete set of common eigenvectors of $\ J\ $ and $\ A\ $ by first finding a complete set of orthogonal eigenvectors of $\ J\ $. When $\ A\ $ and $\ J\ $ commute, the eigenspaces of $\ J\ $ (which must have even dimension) must be invariant subspaces of $\ A\ $, which means that you can find bases for them which are also eigenvectors of $\ A\ $.